# find out all child elements xpath from parent xpath using selenium webdriver in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I can find the element by xpath of  `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')`. but any way i can return all children elements like tag  and tag  xpath?

```
<tr>
    <td class="">
        <div>
            <a href="/user/1">
                <!-- react-text: 6011 -->user first name |
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 6012 -->
                <!-- /react-text -->
                <!-- react-text: 6013 -->user last name
                <!-- /react-text -->
            </a>
            <div>
                <span>
            <!-- react-text: 6014 -->town<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 6015 -->  | <!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 6015 -->month<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 6081 --> | date<!-- /react-text -->
            <!-- react-text: 6082 -->year<!-- /react-text -->
            </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class=""><a href="/address/1">1</a>
        <div class="">city</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you need all the child elements of current WebElement?

Answer (score 20):

The key is to use the xpath `.//*` to get all the children for current node. The `.` picks the current element & `//*` selects all the elements, which makes the whole xpath to select all child elements of current element. Your code will look like this:

```
parent_elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
child_elements = parent_elem.find_elements_by_xpath('.//*')
```

Comment: i am able to find all child_elements, however, I would like to have something like a list contains all child element xpath [ <child 1 xpath>, <child 2 xpath>, ..]

Comment: There really is no generic way of fetching a xpath because there is no 1 xpath for an element. There can be many ways to get an elements xpath.

Answer (score 3):

if you need to find immediate children, use

```
child_elements = parent_elem.find_elements_by_xpath('./*')
```