# How to find last child of html tag in vba selenium

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium

I have the following Xpath for a div tag that has a dynamic number of children:

```
"//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/div[3]"
```

I'm trying to find the last child. I thought about something like this:

```
Dim Children() As Variant
Dim Child As Variant
Children = BOT.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='main']/div[3]/div/div/div[3]").FindElementByXPath("*")
Child = Children(UBound(Children) - LBound(Children))
```

But I get the error

```
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
```

How can I find the last child?

Comment: Maybe see - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43478965/find-out-all-child-elements-xpath-from-parent-xpath-using-selenium-webdriver-in

Comment: Could you please share the url and/or relevant html. And did you try using the .Count method instead? Indexing is from 1 e.g. Children.item(Children.count). Also, please indicate line which raises the error.

Comment: @QHarr It's just a WhatsApp web chat. I'm not familiar with the ```.Count`` method, can you explain?

Comment: Which line produces the error? .Count will return the number of elements in the webElements collection you have retrieved. Indexing starts at 1 so .Count will give you the last item retrieved.

Comment: @QHarr line 3 produces the error

Comment: Can you share the relevant html? Removing any confidential/personal text.

Comment: @QHarr just open a chat in WhatsApp web

Comment: Are you trying to find the last message?

Comment: @QHarr yep, in current chat

Comment: Try `bot.FindElementByCss("[class*='message-']:nth-last-child(1)").text` See if that selector is supported.  Or `bot.FindElementByCss(".focusable-list-item:last-of-type").text`

Comment: @QHarr yes, it is.

Comment: Did it return the expected result?

Comment: @QHarr yes, but I'm actually trying to find the aria label of the message and not the text. ```.Attribute("aria-label")``` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `bot.FindElementByCss(".focusable-list-item:last-of-type span").Attribute("aria-label")` ? Or, `bot.FindElementByCss(".focusable-list-item:last-of-type [aria-label]").Attribute("aria-label")`

Comment: @QHarr returns an empty string

Comment: I can't see the html. In your browser in that chat window, press F12 and then Ctrl + F then enter `.focusable-list-item:last-of-type [aria-label]` in the find box at the bottom of the elements tab and hit enter.... does it highlight the expected element? And can you see a value for aria-label?

Comment: it does, and it has an aria label ```<span data-testid="msg-dblcheck" aria-label=" Read " data-icon="msg-dblcheck" class="_1RD_6">...</span>```

Comment: and is that the roughly the same html you get if you debug.print element.Attribute('innerHTML')? Where element is that matched by css selector I gave?

Comment: @QHarr When using ".focusable-list-item:last-of-type" there are two matches, one for an empty span element and one for the last message. When using "[class*='message-']:nth-last-child(1)", there's only one match - the last message.

Comment: What about `.focusable-list-item:nth-last-child(1)` ? That would be slightly quicker, not that you would notice.

Comment: innerHTML ```<span></span><div class="..."><div class="_3XpKm ..."><span aria-label="You:"></span><div class="..."><div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[10:57, 4/3/2021] Martin: "><div class="..."><span dir="ltr" class="... selectable-text copyable-text"><span><img ...> 
msg</span></span><span class="..."></span></div></div><div class="..."><div class="..." role="button"><span class="_17Osw" dir="auto">10:57</span><div class="..."><span data-testid="msg-dblcheck" aria-label=" Read " data-icon="msg-dblcheck" class="...">...</span></div></div></div></div><span></span></div></div>```

Comment: so looks like that would work as well.

Comment: @QHarr not really, [https://imgur.com/a/OwQxDIR](https://imgur.com/a/OwQxDIR)

Comment: @QHarr any ideas?

Comment: Stick with the one that works

Comment: @QHarr Both selectors result in the same element. it works great for finding the text, but not for the aria-label. It's deeper in the HTML code.

Comment: I think I can treat the HTML as string at this point and extract the aria-label. Thanks @QHarr , you've been of great help.

Comment: No worries. Another thought was `[class*='message-'] [aria-label]:last-child`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a css selector for selecting the last message in active chat based on class attribute.

```
bot.FindElementByCss("[class*='message-']:nth-last-child(1)").text
```